# a4j:commandButton doesn't work

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I'm new to JSF and RichFaces.
I have a button that should call a method on bean. When I use

```
<h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.userLogin}" value="Login" />
```

it works fine, but when I click on

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{loginBean.userLogin}" value="Login" />
```

nothing happens.

My bean code:

```
public class LoginBean {

@Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Must be betwen 2 and 20 chars")
private String          login;
@Size(min = 1, message = "Please Enter your password")
private String          password;

//getters and setters

public String userLogin() {
    //user login code

}
}
```

My JSP Page code:

```
<body>
<f:view>
<div >
   <h:form id="loginForm">
       <h:panelGrid columns="3">
           <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login:" />
           <h:inputText id="login" value="#{loginBean.login}" >

           </h:inputText>
           <rich:message for="login" />

           <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
           <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
           <rich:message for="password" />
       </h:panelGrid>

        <div>
            <h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login}" value="Login" />
            <a4j:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login}" value="Login" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/registration.jsf">Registration</a>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>
</f:view>
</body>
```

So as you can see I even added two buttons. One works fine and second doesn't do anything.

UPD: I didn't use RichFaces at first and my application worked fine. So I guess navigation rules, etc are fine. The thing that doesn't work is a4j:commandButton that I've just added.

UPD2: Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>webappsaichuk</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: can you add your backing bean code?

Comment: added bean and page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method must have a different name from your attribute.

```
public class LoginBean {

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Must be betwen 2 and 20 chars")
    private String login;
    @Size(min = 1, message = "Please Enter your password")
    private String password;

    //getters and setters...

    public String userLogin() {
        //user login code
    }
}
```

```html
<h:inputText id="login" value="#{loginBean.login}" styleClass="rowInput">
<h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.userLogin}" value="Login" />
<a4j:commandButton action="#{loginBean.userLogin}" value="Login" />
```

UPDATE

You should add the RichFaces filter to the web.xml (based on [Getting started with RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html)):

```
<!-- some context params to get better performance for RichFaces -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>classic</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.handleViewExpiredOnClient</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- main filter for RichFaces -->
<filter>
    <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @MaxSaichuk have you written a navigation rule for your JSP page?

Comment: Of course. I didn'f use RichFaces at first and my application worked fine. I tried to add RichFaces. The old functionality still works fine. The thing that doesn't work is a4j:commandButton

Comment: lot of code. It uses few classes that I created. What it actually do is getting user from DB, check if entered password is correct, ataches a message with     FacesContext.addMessage() method and returns string for required navigation rule

Comment: @MaxSaichuk AFAIK the problem could be in your code or the web.xml lacks all or part of the configuration for RichFaces. Maybe if you post that file the community can help.

Comment: added as UPD2 to the main message in topic

Answer (score -1):

a4j:commandButton is an ajax submit. So nothing will happen unless you re-render part of the screen that has changed based on the action.

Comment: His "login" function returns a `String` so the `a4j:commandButton` will do an ajax submit and continue with the navigation rule.

Comment: In my userLogin() method I make a SELECT from DB. I deploy my application to JBoss 6. In the action is performed - I can see a SELECT in log. So I'm sure that my a4j:commandButton doesn't do anything.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure what the point would be. But if that is the case then it should still be re rendering part of the screen for the validation messages.